# How to adapt domain objects to GUI in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, frameworks, eclipse-rcp

I'm new to the architecture of UIs and in the past I've programmed very simple UIs. Now I'm confronted with a very large domain model. Because I've used different OR-Mappers to store domain objects in a flat data structure I thought about mapping the domain objects to the view-side in a similar way.

Are there any patterns or frameworks that address this problem?

More precisely I want to adapt the domain objects to eclipse RCP views in an easy way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Eclipse RCP, I'm not aware of any 'frameworks' for this, but at least the JFace ContentProvider mechanism makes it easy to write a layer of re-usable adapters that handles the presentation of your domain classes in JFace viewers.

If you're after some generic (or starting-point) CRUD screens for domain classes, perhaps you can use code-generation, reflection, and/or dynamic proxies for the ContentProvider classes, taking each domain class (or classes) as input. However, this is rarely as simple as it sounds.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Metawidget](http://metawidget.sourceforge.net/index.html) ?

> Metawidget is a 'smart User Interface
> widget' that populates itself, at
> runtime, with UI components to match
> the properties of your business
> objects.
>
> Metawidget does this without
> introducing new technologies. It
> inspects your existing back-end
> architecture (such as JavaBeans,
> existing annotations, existing XML
> configuration files) and creates
> widgets native to your existing
> front-end framework (such as Swing,
> Java Server Faces, Struts, Android).

I never tried it myself, but it looks like promising for this kind of mapping.

Answer (score 0):

A more complete framework is Naked Objects, of which I'm a committer and also the lead on a number of sister projects.  One of those sister projects is an [Eclipse RCP viewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nakedrcp/), though it is currently stalled.  Feel freed to contact me via my [blog](http://danhaywood.com) if any of this sounds of interest.

-- Dan